# Lebesgues Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I’m going through a proof for Lebesgue’s Monotone Convergence Theorem.

It makes sense to me why
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n d\mu = \sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\int f_n d\mu \leq \int fd\mu$$
My problem lies in the opposite inequality. My textbook states that this is equvalent to showing
$$I_{\mu}(s)\leq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\int f_n d\mu \quad \forall s \in SM(\mathcal{E})^+ : s \leq f$$
and that it is enough to show $$\alpha I_\mu(s) \leq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\int f_n d\mu$$
for any $\alpha \in (0,1)$. This part confuses me, why is it enough to look at $\alpha I_\mu(s)$.

Here, $SM(\mathcal{E})^+$ denotes the set of positive simple measurable functions.

Comment: Why do you need $I_{\mu}(s)\leq \int f_n d\mu$ for every $n$? You only need $I_{\mu}(s)\leq \lim \inf \int f_n d\mu$ and this is  obtained by letting $\alpha \to 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative real numbers, then $x\leq y$ iff $\alpha x\leq y$ for all $\alpha\in (0,1)$.  Indeed, if $x\leq y$ is false, then $x>y$ so $\alpha x>y$ as long as $\alpha>y/x$, and we can pick such an $\alpha$ that is less than $1$ since $y/x<1$.